# R: collapse by ID selecting certain character attributes over others

Tags: r

I want to collapse microdata with multiple observations at different times per ID. Usually an ID has the same birth country but sometimes this changes. I want to collapse my data to one observation per ID and choose the country in a way that never chooses two specific countries (e.g. Canada and Germany). E.g. if there is one observation with birth country Canada and one with US, I want to choose the US. If a person has Italy and Germany I want to choose for example Italy. If there is only one country this should be kept.

My data:

```
ID  birth_country
1   US
1   Canada
1   Canada
1   Canada
2   Germany
2   Italy
2   Germany
3   Canada
3   Canada
3   Canada
```

Should look like:

```
ID  birth_country
1   US
2   Italy
3   Canada
```

I tried it with dplyer and group_by but couldn't figure out a proper way to formulate the selection by character.

Comment: How do you decide which country to choose when there are multiple? Is it random, or do you have a preferred order? If so, is this order available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a `preference` vector that orders the country by preference:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep.int(1:3, c(4, 3, 3)), birth_country = c("US", "Canada", "Italy", "Germany")[c(1,2,2,2,4,3,4,2,2,2)])
preference <- c("US", "Italy", "Canada", "Germany")

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarize(birth_country = preference[min(match(birth_country, preference))])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>      ID birth_country
#>   <int> <chr>        
#> 1     1 US           
#> 2     2 Italy        
#> 3     3 Canada
```

Or `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .(birth_country = preference[min(match(birth_country, preference))]), by = "ID"]
#>    ID birth_country
#> 1:  1            US
#> 2:  2         Italy
#> 3:  3        Canada
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarize(birth_country = first(birth_country))
```

should do the trick. Instead of `first` you can use `last` or `nth` (see `?summarise`)